# Serve static files with django

Tags: django

Setting up a django site but I can't get it to serve static files.
In the settings file

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, os.pardir)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(PROJECT_PATH)

TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'angular/js')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In the template

```
<script src="/static/js/angular.min.js"></script>
```

I can serve the template which is in the main directory `angular` and inside it is the static folder `angular/static/js/angular.min.js`

Answer (score 2):

Add following code in setting.py file

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"deploy_to_server")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

And use in your template

```
<script src="/static/js/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Create static folder in your project

```
==> static ==> js ==> angular.min.js
==> manage.py
```

Hope this is help you

Answer (score 1):

Dont make `STATIC_ROOT` specific for an `app`. It should be of whole project scope.So my recommendation

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

- Then add an `app` named `angular` as any other app.
- Add to `INSTALLED_APPS`
- create folders `static/angular/js` inside it like

  ```
  angular/static/angular/js
  ```
- Copy `angular.min.js` inside it as

  ```
  angular/static/angular/js/angular.min.js
  ```
- access it via `src=/static/angular/js/angular.min.js`

So there will not not be much change in production also.

Comment: You can still use the static tag in the last step - `{% static 'angular/js/angular.min.js' %}`